Detail of a proof of Tutte's theorem
I was studying graph theory when a question came to my mind.
I'm trying to understand a proof of Tutte's theorem [1947]. I need help only for a detail of the proof so I recall the situation.
For every graph G, I call oc(G) the number of its connected components of odd cardinality (in the following, I call them odd components of G). We are given a (finite) graph G of which we know that for every subset S of vertices it is true that oc(G-S)<=|S|. We choose T to be a set of maximal cardinality among those for which the previous formula is in fact an equality (it can be proved to exist and to be non-empty).
At some point of the proof, it is necessary to prove that, for every subset U of T, the number of the odd components of G-T (having a vertex) adjacent to some vertex in T\U is at least equal to |T\U|. I'm having trouble proving the last assertion. The writer suggest to exploit the hypothesis oc(G-U)<=|U|, but right now I cannot see how.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Suppose that there is a $U$ such that fewer than $|T \setminus U|$ odd components of $G-T$ are adjacent to a vertex in $T \setminus U$. What do the remaining more-than-$|U|$ odd components of $G-T$ do, then?
They are either odd components of $G$, or else they are adjacent to some vertices in $T$; however, (by assumption) their neighbors in $T$ must be confined to $U$. Therefore, in fact, they are odd components of $G-U$. This would imply that $oc(G-U) > |U|$, violating the assumption of Tutte's theorem.

I've succeeded in understanding the situation also thanks to your answer. Thank you.
